# recording uplink and downlink separately in different file at once

Tags: android, record

Have anyone tried saving uplink and downlink separately at once in different file? Or saving uplink and uplink+both side in different file.

I found that in a different post that it might be possible using thread because recording channel stays busy. Anyone succeed to do that? Please give me some workable source if possible.

Is it possible at all or not?

Comment: If you had access to the Android source code for your phone and were able to build and flash your own ROM, you could perhaps configure the low-level routing such that a stereo recording from the `VOICE_CALL` AudioSource returned the uplink in one channel and the downlink in the other. But I don't think you can do this from a regular app on a stock Android ROM.